# Getting started with MIDI

Tags: c#, .net, midi

I'd like to write an application that reads USB MIDI data from my midi piano and quite possibly anything else MIDI I can find.

Looking for a library that works with .NET and also allows me to 'intercept' this data even if another application is using the MIDI.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to check out Carl Franklin's Midi library

http://www.franklins.net/dotnet/CarlsMIDITools.zip

And I'm sure he's open to any questions you may have :-)

(And be sure to listen to his awsome .NET podcast: .NET Rocks! (http://www.dotnetrocks.com/))

Answer (score 1):

[NAudio](http://naudio.codeplex.com/) can capture MIDI in C# too, but I'm not sure about intercepting it. You might need to look at something like [MIDIOX](http://www.midiox.com/) for that.